# In powerapps, how do I add a dropdown component so that on any screen, the user could select item from that dropdown and it would be saved?

Tags: dropdown, powerapps

I would like to include in a header a dropdown for the user to provide the location they are at based on a dropdown, this would be collected/saved, but it is a big pain to work with collecting from a bunch of different dropdowns, I think this is where component would come into play. I have seen several videos about header components, and I have not seen any with a dropdown control. Is this doable right now? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set the default property of the DropDown to:

```
First_DD_name.SelectedText.FieldName
```